# Change src attribut with jquery makes container smaller for 1 second... why?

Tags: jquery, html, src, attr, css

I'm trying to create a little slideshow for a mobile website.

This is the html:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <a id="prev" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-role="button" href="#">Previous Image</a>
<div class="gallery-pic">
    <img class="slider" src="images/gallery/chateau-slider-1.jpg" />
</div>
<a id="next" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-role="button" href="#">Next Image</a>
</div>
```

This is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

        var height = $('.slider').height();
        $('.gallery-pic, .slider').css('min-height',height);

        $('#prev').click(function(prev) {
            prev.preventDefault();
            var nameImg = $('img.slider').attr('src').split('/');
            var fileName = nameImg[2].split('-');
            var exp = fileName[2].split('.');
            var numImg = parseInt(exp[0]);
            if(numImg == 1) {
                numPrevImg = 18; }
            else {
            var numPrevImg = numImg - 1; }
            $('img.slider').fadeOut(500, function() {
                $('img.slider').attr('src','images/gallery/chateau-slider-' + numPrevImg + '.jpg');
                $('img.slider').fadeIn("slow");
            });
        });


        $('#next').click(function(next) {
            next.preventDefault();
            var nameImg = $('img.slider').attr('src').split('/');
            var fileName = nameImg[2].split('-');
            var exp = fileName[2].split('.');
            var numImg = parseInt(exp[0]);
            if(numImg == 18) {
                numNextImg = 1; }
            else {
            var numNextImg = numImg + 1; }
            $('img.slider').fadeOut(500, function() {
                $('img.slider').attr('src','images/gallery/chateau-slider-' + numNextImg + '.jpg');
                $('img.slider').fadeIn("slow");
            });
        });
    });
```

Basically, it search for the next image and changes the src attribute.

For 1/2 second the container (.gallery-pic) it become smaller, even if I the min-height property. Note that I'm having this problem with Safari for iPhone. All ok in browsers.

Please help me, I'm going crazy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have a different size set for the container.
Make sure you have a fixed height and width for your container and that it doesn't expand to fit it's children. When you change the src, for a split second there is no image inside, therefore nothing to expand it to fit some size.

Change that in CSS and everything should be fine.

**I am looking at your website from the iPhone simulator.**

**you are setting the min-height to 0 from inside the HTML mark-up or javascript, which is overriding your min-height:160px;set from CSS!!!!**

Also, if you set the min-height to 160px and you have an image with a height bigger than 160px, you will definitely see that effect as well. The container will become slightly smaller before the image goes in to expand it.